# My code below doesn't work for selecting a date from datepicker using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

Here are my codes for selecting the date from that particular website.

```
#expiry date
    date = (sh.cell(row=i+1, column = 6).value)

    date_final = (f'[aria-label="{date}"]')
    store_expiry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="expiry-day-picker"]').click();
    time.sleep(15)
    expiry_date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, date_final).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(30)
```

Please find the inspect code:

```
<table role="presentation"><tbody class="js-CalendarMonth__grid"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">
<button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Saturday, October 1, 2022" tabindex="-1">1</button>
```

Comment: can you share page url please

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It's actually an internal link for company employees alone. People who were employees in our company are only get access to this page. Is there any way I can help you other than this?

Comment: if possible please share html of the page